# git - force lf line endings does not catch binaries

Tags: windows, git, line-endings

according to [Force LF line endings using .gitattributes without losing automatic text/binary inference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26075786/force-lf-line-endings-using-gitattributes-without-losing-automatic-text-binary) when I set my .gitattributes to contain only

```
* text=auto
* text eol=lf
```

then all textfiles should be converted to LF line endings and binaries should be untouched - that's what I want. But somehow, binary files are not being detected properly here. See this output of git bash console under Windows:

```
$ git add .
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in clip2txt.exe.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in raw.png.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in test.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
```

I would have expected, that raw.png and clip2txt.exe are being ignored as they are binaries. The file test will be proper converted, that is fine.

Have I missed something here?`
thank you,
br Alex

Comment: AFAIU the accepted answer the second line is excessive. You need only the first one.

Comment: If I only use * text=auto, then since i am on windows, it will try to convert all files to crlf which is not what i want

Comment: The second line makes **all files** text which is certainly not what you want. Try [`* text=auto eol=lf`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29435156/7976758) in one line.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. It was a short in the dark, and I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone is looking into this, I mark it as answered:

Solution was to set .gitattributes to

```
* text=auto eol=lf
```

Thanks to @phd